# Recording (or transforming after recording) video at non-standard size in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, video-processing

I am trying to capture MP4 video at a specific resolution in Windows Phone 8 (to be specific, 480x480). I know that I can't use sizes other than the presets, and 480x480 is not a preset. How do I transform a captured video (such as 640x480) and crop the top and bottom to make it 480x480? Any free or open source libraries (that run on Windows Phone) are welcome. Please don't answer with answers such as 'use an external server', I need an on-device solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Windows.Phone.Media.Capture APIs and the [AudioVideoCaptureDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.media.capture.audiovideocapturedevice%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) class

Second parameter for AudioVideoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync - see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662975%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) - is the resolution. And you can get the resolutions using AudioVideoCaptureDevice.GetAvailableCaptureResolutions(sensor)

EDIT: To set custom resolutions try [AudioVideoCaptureDevice.SetCaptureResolutionAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.media.capture.audiovideocapturedevice.setcaptureresolutionasync%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

EDIT 2: You could try something like the following to transform recorded video: (can't find where i got the code from soz to author!)

```
StorageFolder isoStore = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFolderAsync("Shared");
        var file = await isoStore.CreateFileAsync("foos1.wmv", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        using (var s = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            Windows.Foundation.Size resolution = new Windows.Foundation.Size(640, 480);
            avDevice = await AudioVideoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync(CameraSensorLocation.Back,
                AudioVideoCaptureDevice.GetAvailableCaptureResolutions(CameraSensorLocation.Back).Last());

            VideoBrush videoRecorderBrush = new VideoBrush();
            videoRecorderBrush.SetSource(avDevice);

            viewfinderRectangle.Fill = videoRecorderBrush;

            await avDevice.StartRecordingToStreamAsync(s);

            Thread.Sleep(30000);

            await avDevice.StopRecordingAsync();
        }


        new MediaPlayerLauncher()
        {
            Media = new Uri(file.Path, UriKind.Relative),
        }.Show();
```

Comment: `AudioVideoCaptureDevice.GetAvailableCaptureResolutions(sensor)` not contains not the desired resolution (For Instance I need 192x144)

Comment: I already use `GetAvailableCaptureResolutions(CameraSensorLocation.Back).Last()` and it returns 640x480 but I need `192x144`

Comment: @PaulZahra I already know how to capture and display/save a video in the preset resolutions. my question is not "how do I capture video on wp8", it is "how do i capture at a custom resolution?". as CAMOBAP also stated, not all resolutions are available.

Comment: Like i said, look at EDITs, edit one specifies SetCaptureResolutionAsync which allows you to specify a size struct variable which contains width, height

Comment: @PaulZahra answer to edit 1:  unfortunatelly it just accepts one of the predefined resolutions (e.g. 640x480, 1280x720, 1920x1080 etc) and anything other than a list of predefined values throws an exception. in case of edit 2: it could be used to display cropped video with the correct layout and transforms set in xaml, but I don't know of a way of recording that cropped to a video file

Comment: You are using AudioVideoCaptureDevice and not VideoCaptureDevice (which is limited to 640 x 480)?